# WPF - STA requirement vs server-side usage

Tags: wpf, server-side

I am trying to use WPF objects (`Drawing`, `Geometry`, `DrawingVisual`, etc) to create random icons for users on the server side of my web site.
When trying to do so in a request processing thread I get an exception "`The calling thread must be STA because many UI components require this`".

Does this message mean that WPF is mostly targeting single-threaded client-side UI? Is this the right choice then for me to use WPF on the server side?  If yes, how to make a workaround for STA exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look there - not directly answering your question, but there is working samples http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2009/12/10/resizing-images-from-the-server-using-wpf-wic-instead-of-gdi.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes WPF is targeted for client side ui or desktop application, check silverlight that is a web version and it can solve your problem as well.